# Added Fragment is not removed and causing App crash

Tags: android, android-fragments

Adding fragment works ok, but removing it crashes app. I thought removing will be straight forward but Im still a beginner so I must missing something. Can you take a look?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Button addFragment, closeFragment;
    android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    android.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager
            .beginTransaction();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        addFragment = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAddF);
        closeFragment = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bCloseF);
        addFragment
                .setOnClickListener((android.view.View.OnClickListener) this);
        closeFragment
                .setOnClickListener((android.view.View.OnClickListener) this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //Instantiate fragment from ExampleFragment class
             ExampleFragment fragment = new ExampleFragment();
             switch(arg0.getId()){      
                 case R.id.bAddF:
                      transaction.add(R.id.fragment_holder, fragment).commit();
                 break;
                 case R.id.bCloseF:
                      transaction.remove(fragment).commit();
                 break;
             }
    }

}
```

Comment: You have to begin transaction before changing something and commit transaction to apply the changes. AFAIK, you cannot reuse a transaction. You need to create a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app crashes because you are saving the `FragmentTransaction` as a member variable. But `FragmentTransactions` **cannot be reused**. Furthermore, you are creating a new `Fragment` everytime, which means that the currently added `Fragment` will not be removed when clicking the remove `Button`.

Do it this way:

```
    private ExampleFragment mFragment;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

          //Instantiate fragment from ExampleFragment class
          if(mFragment == null) mFragment = new ExampleFragment();

          switch(v.getId()){      
              case R.id.bAddF:
                 getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_holder, mFragment, "tag").commit();
                 break;
              case R.id.bCloseF:
                 getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(mFragment).commit();
                 break;
          }
     }
```

Create a new `FragmentTransaction` for each add() or remove() procedure.

As an alternative for keeping your `ExampleFragment` as a member variable, you can use `FragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("tag")` to get the currently added fragment.

Alternative way:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

          switch(v.getId()){      
              case R.id.bAddF:
                 getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_holder, new ExampleFragment(), "tag").commit();
                 break;
              case R.id.bCloseF:
                 Fragment frag = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("tag");
                 getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(frag).commit();
                 break;
          }
     }
```

Comment: ***"FragmentTransactions cannot be reused"*** - any references for that?

Comment: Thx Philipp it does not crashes now, but it does not remove it also. on closeFragment click nothing happens. Is my assumption good that remove() will remove the fragment from the screen?

Comment: Your fragment is not removed because you are creating a new instance everytime. See my updated answer.

Comment: Oh, then remove() removes the newly created instance and not the one I added in layout in the first place. I hope I got it right... Thx